# Output image field in Twig and D8

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I created a basic page with a NID of 176. My basic page content type contains a field called `field_banner_image`.

In my templates directory I created a file called `page--node--176.html.twig` and the template works.

I saw a few threads where you can access the node content via `{{ content.field_name }}`, however, my `content` appears to `NULL` every time.

I managed to output the URL of my image field via:

`{{ file_url(node.field_banner_image.entity.uri.value) }}`

I feel like there has to be an easier/better way of doing this. Any suggestions? Why is `content` null in my twig templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template is named page--node--176.html.twig, it is actually a page template overriding the base page template page.html.twig, so you will have access to all page variables but not those in your node.

Although your node type is called "page", it is still a node, and the template for it would be node--176.html.twig which overrides node.html.twig.

In your node--***.html.twig you will have access to the content variable. Let me know if you need help.